# Can the iPad Magic Keyboard with Trackpad steer the MacOS mouse cursor when iPad is Extended Display for Mac?

Tags: macos, ipad, display, ipados, magic-keyboard-ipad

I have the iPad Pro (12.9" 3rd Generation) running iPadOS 15, and an Intel Mac Mini running MacOS Monterey 12.3.1 (latest versions per of this writing).

The iPad Pro is connected as Extended Display, which shows a MacOS Desktop space on the iPad.

I currently have the Apple Pencil (2nd generation) and the iPad Pro Smart Keyboard Folio (without Trackpad). Both of these devices can control the MacOS computer. The Keyboard be used to type, and the Apple Pencil can control the mouse cursor in MacOS. (NB: Unfortunately, touching the iPad screen via fingers does not control the MacOS mouse cursor).

Can the iPad Magic Keyboard (with Trackpad) steer the cursor when iPad is an Extended Display for MacOS like this? I simply want to be able to control the mouse cursor on my Mac with the iPad's Magic Keyboard Trackpad.

Comment: Mine is latest ipad pro and magic keypad, and unfortunately the trackpad doesn't work as a mouse though the keyboard is working perfectly. 

I found your question as i was looking for a way to make them work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a whim, I purchased the 2020 version of the Magic Keyboard for the iPad Pro 12.9" (3rd Generation), hoping that the answer to the question would be positive.

Unfortunately, the Magic Keyboard's Trackpad ***can not*** control the cursor in MacOS when the iPad is being used to extend the display of the Mac.

This is at least the situation currently (2022-05-23, on MacOS 12.4 and iPadOS 15.5) with the 2020 Magic Keyboard for iPad Pro 3rd Generation. It's possible that the situation is different with the 2021 Magic Keyboard revised version for the 2021 iPad Pro 5th Generation, which I haven't tested. **Please add a new answer if you find a positive solution subsequent to my answer – e.g. with a future version of iPad, Magic Keyboard, MacOS/iPadOS.**

NB: I have decided to keep the Magic Keyboard anyway – instead of using the iPad Pro to extend the display of the Mac, I'm going to use VNC on the iPad Pro to access the Mac (using the app Screens which supports the Magic Keyboard's Trackpad).